# MongoDB Aggregate; Projecting min and max documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
let pipeline = [
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_id",
            minTime: { $min: "$time" },
            maxTime: { $max: "$time" }
        }
    }, 
    {
        $project: {
            // Looking to take the most recent document, and the
            // oldest document for a user and subtract their "weight"
            // attribute
        }
    }
]
```

I am struggling with a MongoDB aggregate problem. I am currently looking to take the oldest document, matching "minTime" and the newest document with time matching "maxTime", and subtracting their "weight" attribute to basically get a net change for the user. How would I go about projecting this in the pipeline?  (time is also a unix timestamp)

Comment: It would be helpful if you can add some sample of your data, the `$group` that you have used in not something which restricts the documents, so if your collection is not Sharded you can perform `$lookup` post this and in it's pipeline use the times to filter it's value.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let pipeline = [
    {
        $sort: {
            time: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_id",
            min: { $min: "$weight" },
            first: { $last: "$weight" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            total: {
                $subtract: [
                    "$min",
                    "$first"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            users: { $sum: 1 },
            total: { $sum: "$total" }
        }
    }
]
```

This pipeline solution ends up utilizing the $first and $last operators after a sort by timestamp.